Statuspage to maintain Dashboard with Prometheus Data
I am trying to use Statuspage to have a Service Dashboard, where I am crawling Prometheus blackbox data using Python script and pushing to Statuspage (api.statuspage.io)
I am able to submit metric to System Metrics and getting displayed as following

but need help with getting following view

Any help is appreciated
